# Selecting rows from an SQL table where entries in the first column have unique values in the second column

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table `countryTable` structured as shown:

```
id | country
---+--------
 1 | US
 2 | GB
 2 | US
 3 | AU
 4 | AU
 5 | CA
 4 | US
```

and I want to select only rows where the id has a single corresponding country - in this case, the output would be

```
id | country
---+--------
 1 | US
 3 | AU
 5 | CA
```

since ids 2 & 4 map to (GB, US) and (AU, US) and not exclusively single countries.

So far, I've tried this query:

```
select * 
from countryTable
group by 1,2
having count(distinct country) = 1
```

However, the result includes the rows with ids mapping to multiple countries.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should group by id only.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to check existence of rows with same `id` and a different `country` value, like this

```
SELECT * FROM data d
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM data dd 
    WHERE dd.id = d.id AND dd.country != d.country
)
```

Output

| id | country |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | us |
| 3 | au |
| 5 | ca |

You can check a working demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=124dd59d36d4e0dc9467bca8bc283327)

Answer (score 4):

Don't group by both ID and country, as that will create a separate group for each combination. Instead, group by ID, and use `min(country)` to retrieve the single country value for those IDs having just one country.

```
select id, min(country) country
from countryTable
group by id
having count(distinct country) = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to collect the unique ids. Your group by is grouping by both id and country and all of them are distinct as a pair.  You can do this by doing a subquery or a temporary WITH query and and an inner join on the results.

```
with uniqueIds(id) as (select id from countryTable
group by id
having count(*)=1)
select countryTable.* from countryTable
inner join uniqueIds u on countryTable.id = u.id
```

Info on how to use WITH clause: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-with-clause/